# In ARC do we need to send removeObserver: explicitly?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nsnotificationcenter

Do we have to send `removeObserver:` explicitly for objects that have been added as observers to an `NSNotificationCenter` before?

I am bit confused and unable to find the exact answer for this.

Please provide me in detail, about this including why we need to removeObserver explicitly, and why don't compiler put it implicitly in class/application?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you need to call `removeObserver:`, if you don't the observed class could call all deallocated instance of the observer.

Comment: Then why dont ARC takes precautions of this? Like it puts [... release]; why it doesnt put [... removeObserver:...] ?/

Comment: Of course NSNotificationCenter knows who's observing: It has to relay the notifications, after all. It seems like they could have used zeroing weak references to ensure that notifications don't get sent to freed observers. But I made a quick demo just to double-check and it does crash if you don't call removeObserver: in dealloc. Dang.

Comment: It doesn't need to be necessary since there can be a weak reference to the observer, but unless Apple explicitly documents that its not necessary, it is necessary. Maybe a feature request we need to make.

Comment: Do you also need to remove observers if you add them to an AVPlayerItem? Once the item finishes playing (AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification), it's automatically removed  from the player. Do I need to manually remove the observers before that happens?

Comment: You should edit your answer to take into account that removeObserver is no longer needed on deinit. (at least for apps targeting iOS 9 or above.)

Answer (score 8):

From 10.11 observers are not required to un-register in their deallocation method.

> NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter no longer
>   send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated. If
>   the observer is able to be stored as a zeroing-weak reference the
>   underlying storage stores the observer as a zeroing weak reference.
>   Alternatively, if the object cannot be stored weakly (because it has a
>   custom retain/release mechanism that would prevent the runtime from
>   being able to store the object weakly) the object is stored as a
>   non-weak zeroing reference. This means that observers are not required
>   to un-register in their deallocation method.[[1]](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_11.html)

Comment: Thanks Parag, for adding this here. Even I was un-aware of this.

Comment: The more time goes by and older SDK's fall out of use, the more correct this answer becomes compared to the other answers. It's a shame that it's listed as the last answer.

Comment: This is true for iOS9 as well apparently (but not iOS8). Ref: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/

Answer (score 5):

Removing the observer is always a smart idea.
If you don't remove the observer, messages will still be sent, even if the object was deallocated. It might even be attached to another object, which would definitely lead to serious trouble.

Comment: It isn't needed if you are targeting iOS 9 and above, which would be pretty much everyone going forward.

Answer (score 2):

You always need to remove observers for KVO as well as for Notifications.