# Is NSNotificationCenter removeObserver in ARC needed?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

Does adding an observer increase the retain count of an object?
If yes, does ARC handle the removing of this observer too? If not, where should I remove the observer?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13911651/730701).

Comment: This is same as I asked few months back :)

Comment: I think it's valid re-asking these questions as I prefer to look for the newest answers to questions in case the perceived wisdom has changed.

Comment: I tested and found that not calling removeObserver in dealloc won't lead to crash when observed object post notifications. Since addObserver not retain observer, is it still need to removeObserver?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You should explicitly remove the observer even you use `ARC`. Create a `dealloc` method and remove there..

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

If you see the method you don't  need to call `[super dealloc];` here, only the method without super dealloc needed.

**UPDATE for Swift**

You can remove observer in **deinit** method if you are writing code in swift.

```
deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
       }
```

Comment: One question: When you call addObserver, is NSNotificationCenter retaining the observer or not? Thanks.

Comment: the notification center won't hold strong references of the observers, so there is not necessary to remove them explicitly in `ARC`.

Comment: It's do need to remove observer in `deinit` method. I've seen crashes related to NSNotificationCenter and it's resolved by removing observer

Comment: This answer is outdated since iOS9, unregistering in dealloc is no longer needed, ref: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/