# Get a UIViewController to push to another controller

Tags: ios, ios7, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a modal view controller that was presented like so:

```
[self presentViewController:photo animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thus photo is a modal view controller, but when its done I want to push to a navigation view controller like so:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    // UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    //nav.delegate = self;

    ProfilesViewController *profile = [[ProfilesViewController alloc] init];
    [_nav pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
}];
```

nav is a property in the photo's view controller that also has delegation.  Still isn't working so what am I missing?

Comment: Wait! Don't forget about **transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:** which MAY be what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Don't complex the thing while it can be done very easily,

In view controller where you're presenting the photo modal view controller, *present it with a notification* like this,

```
[self presentViewController:photo animated:YES completion:^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(pushToNextView:) name:@"someNotification" object:nil];
}];
```

And dismiss your photo modal view controller *with call to that notification* like this,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"someNotification" object:nil];
}];
```

And now you can *push to another view controller* like this,

```
- (void) pushToNextView:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //If you want some value from your notification
    //NSDictionary *someValue = notification.object;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ProfilesViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: okay so instead of object:nil I can do object:@"value" and then grab that value in notification.object?

Comment: Yes, you can. Even you can pass multiple values inside a `NSDictionary` too.

Comment: One issue is it still goes back to the main view controller before the push. I have seen apps not have this.

Comment: @chris, Yes that's right. It should go. But if you really don't want to show `main view controller` just set `animated:NO` while `presenting` and `dismissing` the photo model view controller. This will not give you animation for the same but *may be* not show you `main view controller`.

Comment: the whisper app found a way to do it with animated = yes

Comment: thats how i want it, to dismiss modal is to go back to where you came and to push new photo to picture vc with navigation bar present. both should be animated

Comment: Whisper app developers may applied some present/dismiss/push animation with the same flow.

Comment: PS guys don't forget if you fool with NSNotificationCenter, it is absolutely essential to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656367/is-nsnotificationcenter-removeobserver-in-arc-needed

Comment: hi @cdub - did you ever resolve this?  you should tick and answer, dude